# How can I set new instance for a property class in C#.

Tags: c#, wpf

Actually I want to reset the  SpintexEditorProperty class. This contains the static properties. I want to reset all those properties so that i set new instance but it is not functioning... Please help me... Thanks in advance!

//Reset the SpintexEditorPropertyMain

```
   internal static void ResetSpintexEditorPropertyMain()
   {
       SpintexEditorPropertyMain = new SpintexEditorProperty();

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static properties are not reset when you create a new instance of the class containing those properties. Static fields are meant to remain the same for all the instances of that class.

if you want to reset their values you will have to do them explicitly. Something like this.

```
 public static void ResetStaticProperties()
 {
     SpintexEditorProperty.Property1 = 0;
     SpintexEditorProperty.Property2 = 0;
     SpintexEditorProperty.Property3 = 0;
 }
```

and call this method whereever you want to reset them

Comment: @JayashreeSubramanian my pleasure. But i would recommend you to read the details of static fields.

Answer (score 2):

If class contains static properties then directly access the properties, you don't have to create a new instance to change static properties

Example SpintexEditorProperty.propertyname = null, this will reset the property